# Spark shuffle fails with AccessDenied exception

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, shuffle

I run Apache Spark stream job on cluster with:
`spark.master yarn`
`spark.submit.deployMode cluster`
`spark.shuffle.service.enabled true`
`spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true`
But it fails with **Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1590438937007_0020/blockmgr-ff867859-36d0-4db7-8243-bfabfb3bd40d/0d/shuffle_0_3_0.index**. I run it as *hadoop* user. I cannot understand why process created that file ain't able to read (or modify) it

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: This happens to me when the number of executors are higher than 6